# Lint warning "get is deprecated" when trying to manually inject NgControl

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, tslint

Simple case but could not figure out the answer so far.
From angular v4 when trying to manually inject `NgControl`:

```
this.injector.get(NgControl);
```

The lint starts complaining:

```
get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T>
```

How to properly inject it using **injector**?

Comment: Do you have find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

(Using Angular 8)
This passes without `TSLint` errors:

```
this.injector.get<NgControl>(NgControl as Type<NgControl>);
```

However there is a more elegant solution via the constructor.

```
    constructor(@Self() @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl) {
      if(this.ngControl) {
        this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
      }
    }
```

But you need to bear in mind this is an inline (more elegant) replacement for `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` - you will get a cyclical dependency error using both.

```
   providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FieldComponent),
      multi: true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use it like this now:

```
this.injector.get<NgControl>(NgControl);
```

See the angular documention: https://angular.io/api/core/Injector

```
get<T>(token: Type<T> | InjectionToken<T>, notFoundValue?: T, flags?: InjectFlags): T
```

Comment: `Argument of type 'typeof NgControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<NgControl> | InjectionToken<NgControl>'.`